# AWS Automatic launch script

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, automation, devops

I need to launch an EC2 server automatically from a C# script. Meaning: when a certain flag is flipped true, the script handles ALL the process - choosing & configuring a machine, launching, deploying and then running a script on it.

That being said, I don't mean a scheduler, rather a library/API that automates it completely. Any ideas/references?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions asking for off-site resources (such  books/tutorials, tools/libraries) are off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is the [AWS SDK for .NET](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/) [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/ndg/welcome.html). This will have everything you need to interface with EC2. Also, depending on what you need to do specifically, you should consider whether you should make calls to EC2 directly or whether controlling your EC2 resources via Cloudformation would be a better fit.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like that should do.